# How do I generate correct types for my package?

Tags: typescript, rollupjs, npm-package, .d.ts

I am trying to generate an npm package, so that other devs in my company can use it.
I've almost got everything working, but I can't seem to get the declarations right.

I've tried a number of approaches to generating the file, but in a nutshell when I generate declaration files with tsc, I have two options:

- generate one file as the output, or
- many, which would have the same folder structure as my source code.

Both of these formats have not been useful to my client application. When I generate the single file, my client app complains that the file "is not a module".
When I generate multiple files, there's no "`index.d.ts`" top-level file, so my client app complains.
How should I resolve this?

My npm commands:

```
"prebuild": "rm -rf ./dist",
"build": "rollup -c",
"postbuild": "tsc --project tsconfig.dts.json"
```

My rollup config:

```
import alias from '@rollup/plugin-alias';
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import esbuild from 'rollup-plugin-esbuild';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { dirname } from 'path';

const extensions = ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'];

const rollup = [
    {
        input: './src/components/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
                sourcemap: true,
                exports: 'named',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/index.es.js',
                format: 'es',
                sourcemap: true,
                exports: 'named',
            },
        ],
        external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        plugins: [
            external(),
            alias({
                entries: [
                    {
                        // Replace @/ with src/
                        find: /^@\/(.*)$/,
                        replacement:
                            dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)) + '/src/$1',
                    },
                ],
            }),
            resolve({
                extensions,
            }),
            commonjs(),
            svgr({
                exportType: 'named',
                namedExport: 'ReactComponent',
                exportAll: true,
                babel: true,
            }),
            babel({
                extensions,
                include: ['src/**/*'],
                babelHelpers: 'runtime',
                presets: [
                    '@babel/preset-env',
                    '@babel/preset-react',
                    '@babel/preset-typescript',
                ],
            }),
            copy({
                targets: [{ src: 'src/assets', dest: 'dist', flatten: false }],
            }),
            esbuild({
                include: extensions.map((ext) => `src/**/*${ext}`),
                minify: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
                optimizeDeps: {
                    include: [
                        '@mui/base',
                        '@mui/icons-material',
                        '@mui/material',
                        'uuid',
                    ],
                },
            }),
            postcss({
                extensions: ['.css'],
                extract: 'styles.css',
                plugins: [autoprefixer()],
            }),
            filesize(),
        ],
    },
];

export default rollup;
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "allowJs": false,
        "target": "esnext",
        "module": "esnext",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        // * output .js.map sourcemap files for consumers
        "sourceMap": true,
        "rootDir": "./",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "globals.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "dist",
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        "src/**/*.stories.ts?(x)",
        "src/**/*.mock.ts?(x)",
        "src/**/*.test.ts?(x)",
        "src/app/**"
    ]
}
```

My `tsconfig.dts.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
        // outDir: "./dist/types",
        "jsx": "react-jsx",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "es6"],
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["src/*"],
        },
        "allowJs": true,
        // Generate d.ts files
        "declaration": true,
        // This compiler run should
        // only output d.ts files
        "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
        // go to js file when using IDE functions like
        // "Go to Definition" in VSCode
        "declarationMap": true
    },
    "include": [
        "src/**/*",
        "globals.d.ts"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "src/**/*.stories.ts?(x)",
        "src/**/*.mock.ts?(x)",
        "src/**/*.test.ts?(x)",
        "src/app/**"
    ]
}
```

And here's a sample of what `tsc` generates as output (for the single `index.d.ts` case):

```
/// <reference types="react" />
declare module "assets/empty/index" {
    export { ReactComponent as IllyEmptyDesert } from './illy_empty_desert.svg';
}
declare module "assets/flags/index" {
    import { ReactComponent as Canada } from './Canada.svg';
    import { ReactComponent as United_States_of_America } from './United_States_of_America.svg';
    export { Canada, United_States_of_America, };
}
declare module "components/AdditionalResults/AdditionalResults.definition" {
    import { StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
    import { AdditionalResults } from "components/AdditionalResults/AdditionalResults";
    export type AdditionalResultsStory = StoryObj<typeof AdditionalResults>;
    export interface Result {
        id: number;
        highlighted?: boolean;
        value?: string;
    }
    export interface AdditionalResultsProps {
        mode?: string;
        disabled?: boolean;
        additionalResults?: Result[];
    }
}
```

Any help/advice would be a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I've gotten it resolved, and hopefully this helps someone out there someday.

In a nutshell, I posted this question to the `Typescript` Discord server, and [got an answer](https://discord.com/channels/508357248330760243/1124373627547168779/1124373627547168779) that lead me to the solution(s):

> > When I generate multiple files, there's no "index.d.ts" top-level file, so my client app complains. How should I resolve this?

> your library should  still have an entry point exporting your components
> and  that is this file's typing that should be the entry point for your typings and that you should reference in your package.json

With that, I modified 2 things:

- instead of trying to emit 1 file, I emitted one per component, by setting the `tsconfig.dts.json`
  from:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "./dist/types/index.d.ts",
```

to

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/types",
```

- and then changing the "types" in the `package.json`:

```
"types": "dist/types/components/index.d.ts",
    "exports": {
        ".": {
            "types": "./dist/types/components/index.d.ts",
```